# How to build a SOAP Request from android like SOAP UI request?

Tags: android, soap, soapui, android-ksoap2

Well recently i was debbuging my Android Application but i got a problem when receiving the data from my web service because in the logs, it says that the parameters that i sent (a List) were null...  the thing is... when i test my method with SOAP UI it works!! and i get what i want, but from android the xml request is being built different here is the XML:

SOAP UI (This XML Works!):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ws="http://ws.soap.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ws:GetSomething>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <List>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <id>000001</id>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <type>Sign</type>
     </List>
  </ws:GetSomething>
```

AS you can see this is the xml that SOAP UI built as request to my ws

And this is the XML that i found when debugging on Android:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:GetSomething xmlns:n0="http://ws.soap.net/">
<n0:List>
<id>000001</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
<id>000002</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
<id>000003</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
</n0:List>
</n0:GetSomething>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

So the xml generated by debugging on Android, when i paste on the SOAP UI, just says that the parameters that i sent (a List) were null...

I tested the XML generated in Android and only works if i remove the "n0" prefix before "List" i mean:

from this:

to this:

```
<List>
</List>
```

This is my SOAP Request from Android:

```
  private final String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://ws.soap.net/";
private final StringURL_SOAP="http://MI_IP:PORT/GetSomeRest/WebServiceTest";
private final String SOAP_SOMETHING = "GetSomething";
private final String SOAP_ACTION_GETSOMETHING = "http://ws.soap.net/" + SOAP_SOMETHING;
    public SoapObject SendSigns(ArrayList<Signs> paramSigns)
{       
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_SOMETHING);

request.addSoapObject(buildArray(paramSigns));

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
envelope.bodyOut = request;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes= true;
envelope.dotNet=true;
envelope.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[1];

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SOAP);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETSOMETHING, envelope);

    SoapObject Object = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    if(Object!=null)
    {
        return Object;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("CALL DUMP", "requestError: "+androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d("CALL DUMP", "responseEror: "+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
    Log.e("ERROR: ", String.valueOf(e));

}        
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting space between URL_SOAP and String?

here is ur code:

```
private final StringURL_SOAP="http://MI_IP:PORT/GetSomeRest/WebServiceTest";
```

correct:

```
private final String URL_SOAP="http://MI_IP:PORT/GetSomeRest/WebServiceTest";
```